# Remove all consonants in a string before a vowel then add a character

Tags: javascript, string

I want to remove all consonants in a string before the occurrence of a vowel and then replace it with an 'r'.
  This means that 'scooby' will become 'rooby', 'xylographer' will become 'rographer' and so on. This is the algorithm I came up with:
   1. Check if input type is not a string.
   2. Use a variable(newStr) to hold lowercase conversion and splitted word.
   3. Declare a variable(arrWord) to hold the length of the array.
   4. Another variable called regex to check if a string starts with a consonant
   5. Variable newArr holds the final result.
   6. Search through the array, if the string does not start with a consonant 
      join it and return it.
   7. Else keep looking for where the first vowel occurs in the word.
   8. When found, remove all characters(consonants) before the vowel occurence 
      and replace them with an r.
   9. Join the array together.

I have been able to come up with this:

```
    const scoobyDoo = str => {
    if(typeof str !== 'string'){
        return 'This function accepts strings only';
    }   
    let newStr = str.toLowerCase().split('');
    let arrWord = newStr.length;
    let regex = /[aeiou]/gi;
    for (let i = 0; i < arrWord; i++){
        if (newStr[0].match(regex)) {
            let nothing = newStr.join('');
            return nothing;
        }
        else {
            let vowelIndex = newStr.indexOf(str.match(regex)[0]);
            newStr.splice(0, vowelIndex, 'r');
            return newStr.join('');
        }
    }
}
console.log(scoobyDoo('scOoby'));
```

I tested out the program again by capitalizing the first vowel index and instead of 'rooby' I get 'rscooby'. Why is that so?

Comment: It's an array. `var newStr = str.toLowerCase().split('');` So you can't call `.match` on the whole array - select one of the elements in the array in order to call a string method on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you once try with following code in your else and see the changes

```
else {
  var vowelIndex = newStr.indexOf(str.match(regex)[0]);
  newStr.splice(0, vowelIndex, 'r');
  return newStr.join("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it not much easier like this? Or am I missing something??

```
'xylographer'.replace(/^\s*[^aieou]+(?=\w)/i,function(m,o,s){return "r"})
//"rographer"
'scooby'.replace(/^\s*[^aieou]+(?=\w)/i,function(m,o,s){return "r"})
//"rooby"
```

Comment: it works quite well but I wouldn't mind further explanation of the regex and especially the function (m,o,s).Thanks

Comment: You need to read the js specs a bit. m o s refer match offset and string that is passed to the replacer function. The regex is clear I guess, it matches all the non-vowels untilthe first vovel. The replaces will exchange the match with r. In this case the arguments are not used however when you need to do more complex substitution it will be handy to you.

Comment: thanks. By JS spec did you mean MDN docs or something else? Pls provide useful links

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace                  It boils down to using a replacer function instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

you could just use one reg expression for the whole algorithm and no need to split your string no more.

regexp to use.

/^[^aouie, AOUIE]+(?=[aouie, AOUIE])/g

of course you can readjust regexp to suit you more but this will get your main requirement.

Answer (score 0):

On the line immediately after the else statement, I just called .toLowerCase() on it and it was fixed:
let vowelIndex = newStr.indexOf(str.match(regex)[0].toLowerCase());

Answer (score 0):

I like keeping my code simple and readable

```
function pattern(str){
    var vowelIndex = str.indexOf(str.match(/[aeiou]/)); //returns index of first vowel in str
        return "r" + str.slice(vowelIndex);
}
console.log(pattern('xylographer'));
```